# How to access Azure blob storage via Flex Application?

Tags: flex4, azure

I am trying to access Blob Storage on Azure via my flex Application. I am doing this via an HTTP Service by using the url given by Azure Blob Storage. However, my storage has private and restricted access  and I can only update the storage by using the key (provided by Azure).
Since my application needs to write to this storage, I somehow need to pass in the key via my HTTPService? 
  Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 0):

Azure storage uses a REST Api that's just wrapped by the tools. Heres the official blurb:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179355.aspx

A quick reference for "Get Blob"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179440.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So 1st step is to reference the **Azure Storage REST API** and construct an HTTP request you want to use for your operation, following the API specs.

Once you have that, you will have one header **(Authorization)** for which you'll have to construct a string.  This is the tricky part when you don't have a pre-made library.

The end goal is that you will simply set and pass an Authorization header in your HTTPService object.  This will contain your shared key along with a signature.  This key is a long string that represents the request that is then signed by your Azure key. I really don't know Flex/AS syntax, so I'll do the best to simply describe the solution and you can implement.

---

That signature is a string that you sign with the key.  That string is the combination of the following elements:

- the HTTP Method/verb being used in the request
- the Content-MD5 header value
- the Content-type header value
- the Date
- a concatenized string of all the azure-specific ("x-ms-*") headers
- a concatenzied string of the Azure account name + the blob path you are accessing

So you want to gather/create all this, concat a string with all of them, create a signature of that string using your key, pass that in

*It's important to note that since you send all this in in a single request, the values of these headers is simply based upon what you pass in.  So optional fields (like Content-MD5) that you wouldn't neccesarily use for this can be blank, you just have to pass them.  The signature is simply based on what you send it, there is no two-factor check.*

**Step 1**: Gather the data, just store each of these in a variable, or construct on the fly as you build your string to sign.

*HTTP Method* -- just whatever you are trying to do with Azure.  If reading, use GEt.  If creating, use POST.  If modifying, use PUT.  etc ... This just matched whatever you are already doing

*Content-MD5* -- as mentioned, we don't have to construct a digest here, just use a newline ("\n" in C#)

*Content-Type* -- the HTTPService object has this field.  Set it depending on what you are doing with the API, then reference again for the signing.

*Date* -- again, this is optional as Azure requests pass a custom header for date.  Just append a newline again.  If you want to pass a date, thats fine, just make sure you reference the same value here

*Headers* -- This is a bit language specific, so I'll just describe.  You need to build your request object (based on the Azure API) then access the request's header array, iterate through each, find the ones that start with "x-ms-" and build a long string of them.  You also need to handle duplicates (dont pass) and whitespace.

So if I had 5 headers on my request:

- ContentType: text/xml
- eTag: 10101010
- x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
- x-ms-metadata: SomeData

my header string would be  `Headers[x-ms-version]` + `Headers[x-ms-metadata]`
or

"2009-09-19SomeData"

*Resources* -- this is just your `Azure Storage Account Name + the request Uri` you are accessing.

**Step 2**: Build the string to sign
So you have all this, construct a string of all these variables:

```
string strToSign = HttpMethoid + Content-MD5 +
   Content-Type + Date + HeadersStr + ResourceStr
```

**Step 3**: Sign the string with your storage key

Construct a HMAC-SHA256 hash of this string using your storage account key.  *you'll likely have to download an extension library for Flex.  I don't believe it contains Encryption by default. Just google HMAC-SHA256 Flex and use one of those*

**Step 4**: Build the authorization header
Once you have that hash, you take the whole thing and construct the Authorization Header.  The format is

```
authString = "SharedKey" + [AzureAccountName] + [Signed String you just created]
```

add this to the request, something like

```
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", authString);
```

If you've done all this correct, the request will work.  If not, you'll get a 403.  Once you get it right, store it in a library, b/c trust me you don't want to rebuild :)

Good luck

Comment: Hi all,   Thanks for your responses. I tried building out the flex code as suggested. The issuw which I am facing is that I am getting an HTTP code of 200 which means that my request was successful and delivered, however my xml was not updated on the cloud. I installed Fiddler and saw that I get a message that no Proxy Authenticate header is present. The privacy section states that no P3P header is present.

Comment: it didnt come through.  Add it to the question please

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your key in the HTTP Header.  You can check out this material, which talks about how to talk to Azure storage via the REST API, including updating the header value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx

If interested in some .NET code samples, use Reflector on the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient assembly that comes with the Windows Azure SDK to see how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Flex supports Java, but if it does then instead of writing your own ActionScript wrappers to implement Azure REST API you can use Windows Azure SDK for java. More information about this can be found here: http://www.windowsazure4j.org/